# Can I turn negative number to positive with bitwise operations in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitwise-operators

Is there a direct way how to turn a negative number to positive using bitwise operations in Actionscript 3? I just think I've read somewhere that it is possible and faster than using `Math.abs()` or multiplying by `-1`. Or am I wrong and it was a dream after day long learning about bytes and bitwise operations?

What I saw was that bitwise `NOT` almost does the trick:

```
// outputs: 449
trace( ~(-450) );
```

If anyone find this question and is interested - in 5 million iterations `~(x) + 1` is 50% faster than `Math.abs(x)`.

Comment: abs is not the same as NOT + 1, abs unsigns, NOT + 1 negates. So if you pass in a positive number youll get different results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add one after taking the bitwise negation. This is a property of [two's complement number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). It is not related to Actionscript (aside from the alleged performance difference).

So, `(~(-450)+1)` gives `450`
and `(~(450)+1)` gives `-450`.

***As noted in comments, this answer is written in response to the question, to fix a minor issue in the question asker's experiment. This answer is not an endorsement of this technique for general software development use.***

Comment: Thank you for the link, didn't know about such "two's complement number" thing.

Comment: @rwong just curious; is BitWise better performance than "number = (number < 0 ? -number : number);"  in this negating case

Comment: Careful though, the smallest integer on your system can't be made positive like this, the +1 will cause an integer overflow.

Answer (score 10):

Use the rule that says

```
~(x) = (-x)-1
```

Comment: It probably goes without saying that simple algebra gets you to the formula you wanted, namely `-x = ~x+1` but a good thing to add is that this trick only works for pure integers, and for the smallest possible integer, call it `z`, you actually get back `z` itself, because of the way integers are represented in what is called "twos complement."  So make sure you are doing this for in-range integers only.

Comment: is BitWise better performance than "number = (number < 0 ? -number : number);" in this negating case?

Comment: The expression `number = (number < 0 ? -number : number)` computes the absolute value, while `number = ~number + 1` negates a value. They are two different operations. As for performance, it depends on how the two expressions are compiled. Generally speaking a test like the one you have can lead to [branch prediction fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) and there are super nice compiler optimizations to get around it. But why compare? These are two different operations.

Answer (score 5):

If two-complement is being used (usually the case), negation is complement then add 1:

```
-x == ~x + 1
```

Whether it's faster depends on what optimisations the compiler performs. When in doubt, test.

Comment: +1 for the test suggestion and the remark about how this is complier dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Negation is an operator all unto itself, the unary `-` operator.  Using this is just as fast as using bitwise operations and saves you a lot of typing.

```
negativeX = -positiveX; // is the same as (~positiveX) + 1
```

No multiplication is performed.

If speed is your need, and you don't know if the number is negative or positive, the ternary operator `?:` is faster than introducing the function-call overhead of `Math.abs()`.

```
positiveX = unknownX < 0 ? -unknownX : unknownX;
```

Comment: "the ternary operator ?: is faster than introducing the function-call overhead of Math.abs()" Have you actually tested this? `Math.abs` might avoid an extra branching.

Comment: Note the answer was made in 2011, and there has been significant javascript interpreter development since.  My personal experience is that function calls are _severely_ slower than anything else.  Most of this experience is from many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Basically numbers 2' complement is the number in opposite sign.

```
if (num < 0) {
   PosNum = ~num + 1;
}
else {
   NegNum = ~num + 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var number:Number = 10;
//Makes a number
trace(number)
//Tells you the number BEFORE converting
number = number - number * 2;
//Converts number
// Takes number times 2 and subtracts it from original number
trace(number);
//Tells you the number AFTER converting
```

In the end, all you need is this:

```
var number:Number = 10;
number = number - number * 2;
```